# How to poll server using Service and ASyncTask and update UI

Tags: android, android-asynctask, polling

I am currently using ZXing Barcode reader to scan a QR code. Using the API, the ZXing code has a "onActivityResult()" method to handle success or failure scans.

If it is successful, I call the checkQR class, which consists of a ASyncTask. Currently it returns the results once, as it is only called after scanning.

How do I keep calling/polling at an interval of 30 seconds, Update the textView and stop it (kill the service) after it detects a certain text (for example "it is done")?

Note: CheckQR constructor takes in a Context and TextView. 
orderstatus is the TextView which i wish to update the response from the server.

**Partial code for onActivityResult()**

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (scanResult != null) {
        String contents = scanResult.getContents();
        if (contents != null) {             
            orderNum.setText("Order Number: " + contents);
            new CheckQR(this,orderStatus).execute(contents);
        } else {
        //failed
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to execute CheckQR(this,orderStatus) every 30 s ?

Comment: @inmyth Yes I do, as CheckQR contains the code the the ASyncTask.

Comment: Hi @inmyth, can you help me with is? can someone else help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are too many caveats with your question.
Do you want this scheduler to keep running outside Activity ?
Do you want to rigidly call CheckQR every 30s even if the previous one has not completed ?

I am assuming you want to call CheckQR for as long as your Activity lives because it updates a `TextView`.
So if you want to make a chain call which starts after CheckQR completes then you can simply do it recursively with `Handler` in `onPostExexute`.

```
private CheckQR cqr;

class CheckQR extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        if (isCancelled()){
            return null;
        }
        String res = httpCall();
        return res;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result == null || isCancelled() || result.equals("it is done")){
            return;
        }
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                cqr = new CheckQR();
                cqr.execute();
            }
        }, 30000);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    cqr.cancel(true);
}
```

If you want to start CheckQR every 30s no matter if the previous one has completed or not then use `ScheduledExecutorService`

```
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
            Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

        ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate
            (new Thread(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //do blocking http call

                    if(stopCondition)//when stop condition is met
                        scheduledFuture.cancel(false);

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (!flagActivityOnDestroyedRaised){
                                // you need this flag to prevent 
                                // updating UI when Activity is already 
                                // destroyed
                                textView.setText("aaaa");
                            }

                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Clean up in onDestroy

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    scheduledFuture.cancel(false);
    flagActivityOnDestroyedRaised = true; 
}
```

This code is just a pseudo code. You need to declare some of the references here as instance variables and use the right methods. If you use `ScheduledExecutorService` then you need to unwrap your AsyncTask into `Thread` with `runOnUiThread`.

Comment: I saw many people recommending 'runInUiThread()' but i have no idea how to implement that. I went with Handler and it seems to be able to poll at intervals now. I declared it in 'onActivityResult()' though. CheckQR is a class by itself. I just need to figure out how to stop polling once a condition is met.

Comment: In AsyncTask, runOnUiThread is equal to onPostExecute and onProgressUpdate because they are meant to update UI like your TextView. If you have time however, learn a bit about RxJava. This is functional programming paradigm which destroys AsynsTask.